# Error: "No Such Module 'AVFoundation' "

Tags: swift, import, avfoundation, watchkit

What's the problem here? I searched the web, and there aren't really any other instances of this. I tried cleaning and restarting Xcode, I deleted the code and tried again, I've already linked the binary with the library AVFoundation in the project . . . what's up with this? I know that it should work, because I'm doing it from a video tutorial of the current Watch OS and Xcode version, and there are no other students taking the tutorial with the same issues. But it just doesn't work like normal.

[image: Screenshot of Xcode]

Here is my code in text:

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import AVFoundation


class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)

        // Configure interface objects here.
    }

    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()
    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
        super.didDeactivate()
    }

}
```

Hope you guys can help!

Comment: I was only using a screenshot so you could see the error.

Comment: But you're still doing it. _Copy_ your _real_ code and _paste_ it directly into your question. Only that way can _we_ copy from your question into code and try it. - You can copy and paste the error message as well (from the Issue navigator).

Comment: Haha . . . OK then, if that makes it easier for you.